# mongod data directory not changed, ubuntu 15.10 gnome

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I installed mongodb as instructed in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), using `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`. (I imported the key, created the list, then installed the package).

Now when I enter the terminal and type mongod I get the following error:

```
2015-11-10T16:39:18.682+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2015-11-10T16:39:18.682+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

so I went to /etc and edited the mongod.conf file with a path to en empty directory I created in the home folder:

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /home/shooshte/mongo-data/db/
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:
```

and I'm still getting the same error. What am I missing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wrong place to ask, off-topic here. Voted to migrate this question to http://dba.stackexchange.com Please do ***not*** double post. Either delete here and post there or wait for migration.

Comment: Thanks, will wait for migration